# Can OpenMDAO co-operate with autograd or jax?

Tags: openmdao, autograd, jax

Could the autograd or jax packages be used to generate the equivalent of analytic derivatives for OpenMDAO explicit components? i.e. something more accurate than finite differences (or perhaps more accurate or more general than the complex step method?) but without the work of manually computing and programming the analytic gradients?

I'm not an expert on either of these packages, but they seem to be designed for just this purpose.

Comment: We've done some experimentation with jax and OpenMDAO.  It works but the performance doesn't seem to be quite as good as analytic derivatives at the moment, but  this may be due to lack of experience on our part.

If your model is complex-compatible, complex-step is typically accurate to machine precision.  If sparsity is important for performance, as it is in Dymos, then we've found that using the sparsity detection for finite-difference/complex-step works quite well:  https://openmdao.github.io/dymos/faq/use_partial_coloring.html

Comment: I'll tack on to what Rob said and say that Jax does make sense in some cases, just as you say. There are a lot of subtleties and trade-offs that make its efficiencies model-dependent. I did some quick comparisons of different derivative computation costs here, but know that any trends will be model-dependent as well. Just read the readme on this GitHub page for my findings. https://github.com/johnjasa/derivative_comparisons

Comment: Thank you! I'd accept these as an answer if they were designated as such.